# Почему при build сборке vue приложения все равно кешируются файлы, хотя они каждый раз разбиваются на chanks с рандомными префиксами

Tags: javascript, vue.js, кэширование

При сборке vue приложеня npm run build в продакшн менеджеры все равно не видят изменений пока не сбросят кеш, как избавиться от этого? Единственный файл, чье имя не изменяется - точка входа - index.html Может ли из-за одного него так происходить?

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего им приходит старый index.html с ссылками на старые скрипты

На одном из проектов где актуальность кода была критична. При сборке создавалось 2 файла с ключом последнего коммита сборки

- build_version.js - в нём была константа с id коммита и он был в сборке
- tag.json - так же содержал id коммита при сборке, лежал в папке приложения.
  При запуске сайт делал запрос к tag.json с хедером (Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store) и сравнивал её с константой в сборке. При отличии просил обновить страницу

Comment: Я думал что скорее всего из-за index.html, он единственный без изменений названия файл в сборке. Интересное у вас решение, но хотелось бы избежать лишних запросов,

Comment: Такое решение так же позволяет избежать ошибки если пользователь по какой то причине не обновляет страницу и не закрывает её, что в принципе не обновит скрипты

Answer (score 0):

Задачу сброса кэша при каждой новой сборке можно решать так.

Суть подхода:

1. vue-ssr с использованием шаблона.
2. Использование актуальной даты как query-параметр для сброса кэша.
3. Передача параметра даты с помощью node.js

Этот метод потребует прокидывания переменных в шаблон.
Так же можно использовать только webpack-плагины для этого, чтобы вставлять актуальную дату в шаблон и тогда кэш будет сбрасываться автоматически.

В коде шаблона html - `path-to-build-folder/main.js?date={{calc_date}}`. Это приведет к сбросу кэша при каждой новой сборке.
calc_date можно передавать с помощью **node.js**

```js
  output: {
    path: 'path',
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/public/build/',
    chunkFilename: '[id]_[contenthash].js',
  },
```

Если использовать чанки для файлов - перезагрузится в итоге точка входа, часть чанков останется закэшированной, новые - будут подгружены.

Comment: Тоже интересный метод, но опять таки, у нас на сервере php, ssr тут не подходит(